# Creating a gradient overlay over a scrollable element

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable element which I would like to overlay with a gradient. Yet I have tried using :before and fixed/absolute positioned elements. However, either it doesn't fit well or the overlay doesn't allow me to scroll down anymore.

I must be overlooking something simple. Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Week 1</li>
<li>Week 2</li>
<li>Week 3</li>
<li>Week 4</li>
<li>Week 5</li>
<li>Week 6</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
text-align:center;
width:40%;
height: 300px;
overflow: auto;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}

ul li {
margin: auto;
position:relative;
cursor: pointer;
padding:30px;
background-color: #FBFBFB;
font-size:30px;
vertical-align: middle;
display:block;
}

.center{text-align:center;}
```

Here's the fiddle which contains my basic structure:
https://jsfiddle.net/dnw0o19k/

Comment: I don’t see any gradient in your code. Anyway, `pointer-events` should be able to fix your issue.

Comment: You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dnw0o19k/1/

Comment: Something like that. I should have mentioned in my real site, I have the list items alternating colours. Your answer did make me realize I could've made a normal gradient background and then just put some opacity on my list items background. I will try this out right now :)

Comment: Yess that works, thanks Karacsi_maci for making me realize and thanks CBroe for the tip :)